# Code to compare to columns, find differences, and paste them in a new column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just trying to compare columns `A` and `D` and see if there is any value in `A` that is not in `D`. Then, I want to copy that value and the adjacent cell, Column `B`, and paste them in Columns `G` and `H`.

For example, in the photo, the expected outcome would be `wilsona` in `G3` and `Last, First2` in `H3`. The number of rows will be variable and `A` and `D` will probably never have the same number of rows.

All I have is the code below. The issue is it is only comparing, for example, `A1` to `D1` instead of to the entire range of `D`:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For i = 3 To 20
    If (Range("A" & i).Select <> Range("D" & i).Select) Then
        Range("A" & i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("G" & i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("B" & i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("H" & i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next i
```

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Without a shown attempt, I think this will be judged as too broad for Stack Overflow. Would you show what code you have been working on?

Comment: @iogoja, do you have any code at all?

Comment: I just added what I have. I didn't include it because it was so basic I didn't even think it was worth anything

Comment: OK  try the answer I put below and let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your scenario:

```vb
Sub Macro1()

Dim ws as Worksheet
set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Compare")

Dim rngA As Range, rngD as Range, MySel as Range

Set rngA = ws.Range("A3", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set rngD = ws.Range("D3", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rngA
    If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, rngD, 0)) Then
        If MySel Is Nothing Then
            Set MySel = cell.Resize(1,2)
        Else
            Set MySel = Union(MySel, cell.Resize(1,2))
        End If
    End If
Next cell

If Not MySel Is Nothing Then MySel.Copy Destination:= ws.Range("G3")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!